How would fantasy sea monsters fare, up against modern technology?
How would classical sea monsters, such as krakens, giant sea serpents, etc. fare against modern technology such as depth charges, naval ships, torpedoes, sonar, etc.?
Assume the following:

Humanity coevolved with these creatures, this isn't a portal to another dimension scenario. Any sea monster in consideration can't be so extreme that humans could not have evolved. Likewise these sea monsters would not have been hunted to extinction.
Technology between WW I and now
A similar, or as much as possible, usage of the ocean by humans as here on earth.

Some leading questions

How effective would sonar be at detecting these creatures?

What weaponry would be effective at killing or deterring sea monsters?

What other technology comes to mind for dealing with these creatures?


( For the biology of these creatures you can simply work with similar existing creatures but scaled up. )

1 question per post. You are asking us a book with all the sea monsters, which who knows how many are they?

So, what's your Kraken like? Sea-serpent etc.? If you say they're invulnerable or made of custard, then who are we to argue.

@Escapeddentalpatient. Logic dictates roughly usual biology.

what sea monster there are thosands of sea monstrs from mythology and literature. You need to define what the anatomy and capabilities of your creature is first. downvoting until you come up with specifics.

@GraySheep -- In this forum, assume that at your own risk!

They have no chance. Note that simple harpoon gun can kill the whales since centuries.
That is an ak-47 projectile penetrating about 25cm thick trees, or the densest part of cow bone (link). And these are yet nothing more advanced, like torpedoes, sea drones or even battleship guns.
They are much lesser visible in the sonar, but still visible. Other answer says, industrial fishing finds fishes by sonar.
We still did not talk about yet more advanced things like bacterial or chemical weapons which could be developed and used underwater.
Their only chance is surprise or if also they have some intelligence or technology (with a minimal intelligence, they also can get help from humans).

I have to assume that you pasted the wrong link... unless Taylor Swift has started showing some very strange things at her concerts

@MS Pfff :-) I fixed and improved the post.

It depends on what they attack...
While marine life can be detected with sonar, the range is rather limited. Submarine warfare relies more on listening passively to the sounds made by enemy ship engines because these sounds tend to carry much farther, than a bounced echo. Moreover, the sound made by something using echolocation will always be much louder to the target than to the receiver. Since the sea monsters don't have any loud diesel engines giving them away, it means that they will typically become aware of a human ship long before a human ship becomes aware of them.  This gives the sea monster a lot of latitude to decide if it wants to engage any given human ship or not.
World Wide, there are currently about 30 million privately owned small boats, 100 thousand merchant vessels, and only 3350 military warships. This means that if a sea monster were to attack any random ship, there is only about a 1:1000 chance of them having to face off against any sort of heavy firepower.
Yes, a kraken vs a modern warship is beyond screwed, but they will almost never actually go head to head with warships because they are smart enough to avoid them.  Large marine life tends to be fairly intelligent creatures. An aircraft carrier task force is an obvious no go, and a several thousand ton merchant ship is probably bigger than any sea creature would imagine taking on, but the sound of a small, lone fishing ship dragging its nets through the water sounds like a free meal.
Laws prevent non-military ships from carrying most weapon systems.
Logically, this just means smaller private ships will start carrying heavy firepower, but the real world suggests this will not be the case.  People often wonder why modern merchant ships don't simply carry enough firepower to fend off piracy, and the answer is that they are not allowed too.  Modern weapons are so destructive that most of them are not allowed within a certain range of any major port; so, even if a mid-sized cargo ship would WANT to carry depth charges, they would not be allowed to. In our world, it's already been decided that occasional piracy losses are a smaller risk than lifting port restrictions; so, as long as Sea monster attacks are not too common, the same thinking would likely remain true.  At most, the average ship is allowed to enter port with small arms, and even that is not true in every country.  So even in a modern setting, the best defense the average ship might have could still just be a spear.
Seamen would have to get creative with how they arm themselves being careful not to run afoul of laws or animal rights groups.
How governments will try to control sea monster attacks
Hunting sea monsters is not going to mean needing a special fleet of ships designed to mimic defenseless small boats.  During WWII, the allies had such a hard time hunting down german submarines that they made up a new class of warship called Q Boats: well armed ships designed to mimic harmless shipping vessels to lure subs into attacking them.
This means that when sea monster attacks do get out of hand, governments may commision small, harmless looking ships to hunt them down.  These Q boats will have the advantage of superior firepower and will very rarely lose a fight, but they will be much more size and technology limited than historical Q boats if you want to keep them small enough to lure in sea monsters; so it will still be a much more fair fight than if a sea monster were to try to take on something like a Arleigh Burke class destroyer or other such modern warship with anti-submarine capabilities.
The thing about sea monsters though is that driving them to extinction is a lot harder than just ending attacks on civilian ships.  Sure you can kill off any individual monster that gets a taste for seamen, but if 9/10 sea monsters always avoid human ships, then they could maintain a healthy population too deep to root out even when you kill every last sea monster you can find.

Whilst true you can't bring most weapons into most ports, its not unheard of for shipping companies to hire armed security to protect their ships on occasion. Its more work but it isn't impossible to bring larger weapons like .50 caliber rifles. There's also a fairly obvious work around, just don't bring the weapons into port. Park a ship in international waters outside ports with a large arsenal of weapons. When a ship leaves port, contractors rent weapons from the other ship for the voyage then drop them off at another ship at their destination.

@ChellCPlus Sure, there will always be creative acceptions, but unless monster attacks are really common, most people will not bother, just like most people coming from a city with strict gun control laws will not carry a gun to go camping even though they might get attacked by a bear or jaguar.

That very much depends on the location, in some areas of the world you're basically required to bring a firearm in case of bears/hogs. Even in areas with relatively strict gun control, having a firearm with you in a remote area that contains dangerous animals is fairly standard practice.
I know sure as hell if there was "sea monsters" off the coast I'd be bringing some sort of effective defense.

Without any form of serious Intelligence - Even something like a Kraken would get absolutely mauled by anything from WW2 onwards
You said in your blurb that for Biology, we are simply scaling up current equivalents.
In which case - yes, they could be detected by SONAR - the Software would need to be tweaked in order to look for their signals or at least not filtering out the returns (my understanding is that the system is capable of detecting fish, but these are filtered)
Some open-source info indicates that something like a Whale can be detected by SONAR (passive) at 5-15 Miles.
Depending on the sensitivity and detection methods the Kraken has - either the Vessels detect them first or they both detect each other at the same time.
This is the first issue for any mythical sea creature:
Lack of Ranged options
Using the Wikipedia article for the British Spearfish 21 inch heavy torpedo - it can do 148 Kph for 56 Km.
So even if they both detect each other at the same time - there is a period of time where the Submarine or Destroyer or Carrier (thanks to air-dropped Torpedoes) can engage the target without the target being a threat.
Then we have the effect on target - Water is not Compressible. Underwater munitions use this fact to devastating effect. The initial blast is bad, but the follow-up pulses are what will break the keel of a ship and cause it to sink quickly. Against a Biological enemy - they would in all likelyhood get a big chunk of their body turned into a pulp and the follow-up waves would wreak havoc.
Then all the fishes with a score to settle would finish the job.
If they are on the surface - then Cannon fire from a Naval gun would pop them like a can.
However, you will note I said without any form of serious intelligence
Let us assume that these Krakens have Human levels of Intellect - now we can have some fun.
Taking advantage of Thermalcline layers, hiding with shoals of fish, taking advantage of SONARs blindspots, wrapping itself in Kelp and other material to minimize a SONAR return.
This allows the Kraken to get in close - and this is where actually, it is a pretty far fight.
A Ship or a Submarine is probably topping out at around 30 ish knots (unclassified) - well, Marine animals can hit speeds in this region.
A Sea creature can definitely out-turn and out-maneuver at close range a Ship or Sub.
Furthermore - if they know to cut the guiding wire - this rules out Torpedoes (too much risk of Friendly fire).
Which limits us to Depth Charges, but again - if they stay close-ish to the surface, this limits the ability to use Depth Charges and the ability to use cannons, Rifles, Ma-Deuces etc. on the target.
Things like a Hedgehog (Spigot mortars) which athough arent seen on Western ships, still exist on Russian equipment - would probably be the best bet.
In terms of offense - a Kraken with human levels of intellect could attack the Rudder, the Prop shaft, put holes in the Hull, tear off towed SONAR arrays etc.
But we do have to put some Caveats - namely, we could respond very quickly by up-armouring the hulls and developing weapons systems to counter such a threat.
To conclude - if it has Human levels of Intelligence, there are scenarios where a Mythical creature could get close to a Naval vessel and pose a significant threat

I think an answer is possible without going into details for the monsters.

Fishing craft use active sonar to detect shoals of fish. Detecting a few bigger ones that way should be practical. Likewise, submarines may have problems to tell possible submarine contacts from 'biologicals' at first. Refining the contact, they can usually tell. So telling 'biologicals' from subs should also work.

The ability of any large biological creature to resist a direct hit with a torpedo or depth charge looks questionable. Just one stick of dynamite can kill the fish in a lake. Making the monster survivable against that would require either improbable toughness or an ability to reconstitute after damage, more a swarm like a classic sea monster.


If the monsters have to surface, think of a cross between a 20th century whaler or a corvette. In fact, some corvettes were based on whaler designs. Using sonar and depth charge throwers, they can fight more-than-whale-sized monsters.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_depth_bomb is a really big stick of dynamite

@JonCuster, those tend to be used by aircraft only, ships would sink themselves. The joke was that nuclear torpedoes hat a kill probability of 2.0 (i.e. two subs per shot, when the normal number was a bit below 1.0 ...

ASROC tipped with a nuke was mounted on many surface ships. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RUR-5_ASROC

@JonCuster, to create the necessary standoff, using a rocket instead of a plane.

For subs there was SUBROC as well.
